# C# accept number and display its incrementing value using loop statements

Tags: c#

im new to programming and we have our first activity which is to write a program that will accept a number then display its incrementing values using an array and loop statement. I tried but my code does not meet the corret way so i hope anyone can help mwle btw this is my code...

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input a number: ");
int put = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[] array = new int[put];
Console.WriteLine("Incremented number: ");

for (int j = 1; j <= array.Length; j++)
{
    //  put = put + 1;
    Console.WriteLine(j);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What does "display its incrementing values using an array and loop statement" mean? Can you post the exact requirements of the task?

Comment: `int[] array = new int[put];` creates a new array of type `int` with a size of `put` elements. Each of these values ist non-set, which is 0 for int. `array.Length` returns the length, the number of elements (=`put`). To access the value of an array, try `array[INDEX]`, where INDEX is the position of your wanted value.

Comment: "our first activity" sounds like you are doing this in/for a programming class. If that is the case, the most appropriate person to ask would be your teacher. It is (literally!) their job to help you. They can do this better than we can, because they know about the teaching goals of this exercise and we don't. Remember that the point of a programming course is *not* to get a working program as fast as possible, but to try things, to make mistakes, and to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you haven't specified all the requirements, it's not completely clear what you need to do, but I assume you're asking how to populate the array and then output numbers from the array?

The typical pattern would be something like:

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of times to increment: ");
int put = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // Not the best way to do it, but ok

// Initialize an array with the specified number of elements
int[] array = new int[put];

Console.WriteLine("\nIncremented numbers: ");

// Since arrays are 0-based, start with 0 in our loop
for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
{
    // Add 1 to the current index and assign it to the appropriate array index
    array[j] = j + 1;

    // Output the number from the array to the console
    Console.WriteLine(array[j]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```